# Making proportions equal

Tags: mathematics

A bag is filled with wheat and rice in proportions of 3 and 5 respectively, and they are completely mixed. What proportion of the bag should be emptied and replaced with wheat so that the proportion of wheat and rice become equal?

Comment: You want the bag to have 5 parts rice, 3 parts wheat and 2 parts emptiness, which adds up to 20% emptiness. Math textbook problems have been deemed "off topic" by the community on this site, and I'm afraid this is a prime example of one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace

> $\frac{1}{5}$ of the bag with wheat.

Reason:

> Let's call the fraction that is taken out $x$. At the beginning the bag contains $\frac{3}{8}$ wheat and $\frac{5}{8}$ rice. After taking out the fraction $x$ it contains only $\frac{3}{8} \left( 1 - x \right)$ wheat, but after the replacement it has $\frac{3}{8} \left( 1 - x \right) + x$ wheat. To have equal proportions of rice and wheat, this should give $\frac{1}{2}$, so we have the equation $$\frac{3}{8} \left( 1 - x \right) + x = \frac{1}{2}$$ which solved for $x$ gives $$x = \frac{1}{5}$$
>  A quick check shows that this is also the fraction of rice that is contained in the bag at the end: $\frac{5}{8} \cdot \left( 1 - x \right) = \frac{5}{8} \cdot \frac{4}{5} = \frac{4}{8} = \frac{1}{2}$.